# Java 6: How to set up UndoManager to work with a canvas?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jpanel, undo

I am trying to set up `UndoManager` in a paint-like program, but miserably failing at that. The sample programs, which I have been looking at, are text editors ([Example](http://www.example8.com/node/view/id/18933)) and they call the method `addUndoableEditListener` of class `JTextComponent`.

How should I set up UndoManager to work with a canvas?

```java
public class Pisi extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener,
    UndoableEditListener {
ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> store = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
ArrayList<Point> pts = new ArrayList<Point>();
ArrayList<Point> newRed;
ArrayList<Point> currentRed = new ArrayList<Point>();
JPanel panel;
Point start;
static int xsize = 500;
static int ysize = 350;
int listNumber = 0;
int lastPointed = -1;
int pointed = -1;
int clicked = -1;
UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();
UndoAction undoAction = new UndoAction();
RedoAction redoAction = new RedoAction();
protected MyUndoableEditListener l = new MyUndoableEditListener();


public Pisi() {
    panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };
    setSize(xsize, ysize);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    panel.setLocation(0, -11);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    **this.addUndoableEditListener(this);**
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pisi d = new Pisi();
}

*... more code...*
}
```

All input will be well appreciated.

Comment: Can you set up it to work with panel?

Comment: It seems you are not right about listener, panel, canvas. Sorry, I don't understand what are you talking as it contradict with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create edit classes for all user actions that should be undoable/redoable. These classes must implement [UndoableEdit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoableEdit.html)  (preferably by subclassing [AbstractUndoableEdit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/AbstractUndoableEdit.html)). Then you can use these edit classes with instances of [UndoManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html) and [UndoableEditSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoableEditSupport.html).

You can add UndoableEdit objects directly to UndoManager (it has an addEdit method). If you want to manage UndoableEditListener objects (for example to notify menu items or buttons), you can use UndoableEditSupport for that - it has the addUndoableEditListener that you are looking for.

Comment: @Ibalazscs, would you care to provide an example of such class?

Comment: Well, once I wrote an open source image editor that has unlimited undo support, you can download the source code from here: http://pixelitor.sourceforge.net/ (this code is in the pixelitor.history package)

Comment: @Ibalazscs, is it a separate download? I could not find a download with such name.

Comment: See all downloads/1.1.2 folder/pixelitor_1.1.2_src.zip